# What does "sometimes I’ll have the impression" mean here?

Tags: meaning, literature

I would like to know what "sometimes I’ll have the
impression" means in the following sentences:

> A couple of times my gaze snags with Will’s over her shoulder. I don’t
> think it’s my fault: **sometimes I’ll have the impression** that his
> eyes have been on me for a while. It shouldn’t be, but it’s exciting.
> It reminds me – I know it’s totally inappropriate to say this – but it
> reminds me most of that feeling you get when you start to suspect that
> someone you’re attracted to fancies you back.
>
> I catch myself in the thought. Reality check, Hannah. You’re a married
> mother of two and your husband is right there and you’re talking to a
> man who is about to get married to your husband’s best friend, who is
> standing looking like Monica Bellucci, only better dressed. Probably
> ease off the champagne a little. I’ve been knocking it back. It’s
> partly nerves, surrounded by this lot. But it’s also the sense of
> freedom. No babysitter to embarrass ourselves in front of later, no
> small people to have to wake up for in the morning. There’s something
> exotic about being all dressed up with only other adults for company,
> a plentiful supply of booze, no responsibility.

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 12

This is a thriller novel published in 2020 in the United Kingdom. One hundred and fifty guests would be gathering at some remote and deserted fictional islet called Inis an Amplóra off the coast of the island of Ireland to celebrate the wedding between Jules (a self-made woman running an online magazine called *The Download*) and Will (a celebrity appearing in a TV show program called *Survive the Night*). The day before the actual wedding day, Hannah, the wife of Charlie (Jules' friend), arrived at the island and is now at the dinner party for the rehearsal dinner with only some selected guests. And during the party, Hannah sometimes feels that Will's eyes had been on her for a while.

In this part, I wonder what "I'll have" means.
It is combined with "sometimes," so I doubt this "will" would mean the future tense, but then I cannot quite understand what "will" means here in particular.

Comment: The party is being described in the present tense, to give the reader the feeling of seeing it through Hannah's eyes as it happens. One of the uses of _will_ is 'expressing habitual behaviour'. She has been getting this impression a number of times during the evening.

Comment: Dear @KateBunting, thank you very much for the explanation. So "will" here means "habitual behaviour"! I sincerely appreciate your help. :)

Comment: 'Will' doesn't _mean_ habitual behaviour, but it can be used to express the idea of it, as in  "He will often sit reading until midnight".